# How can we export test cases from Microsoft foundation server(TFS) to an excel format?

Tags: python, tfs, export-to-excel

I have test cases created in Team Foundation server, now I want to export those test cases from Microsoft foundation server(TFs) to excel format for the reporting purpose. We  do have in-built option of exporting test,email or print  in  word format, but Is it possible to  write some python code to export the tests cases directly into excel sheet.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Comment: Yes, the solution works, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export to Excel(work item type):

You can use below way to export test cases(work items) from TFSto MS excel:

1. **Define a query for the test case you want to export.** Create new
   query for all test case -> `specify Work Item Type` = `Test case.`

[image]

2. **Connect in MS excel.** MS excel -> Team ribbon -> New List -> Servers
   -> add -> input VSTS URL(https://tfsseverurl.com) -> OK -> Close -> select a team project -> connect -> choose Query list ->
   select the query you just created -> OK.
   [image]

Now all the test cases are export to MS excel. And you can click Choose Columns to add or remove displayed columns which corresponding to selective fields.

[image]

**Note:** This will not include test steps.  For test steps, it's still a user voice:

[Exporting Test Cases with Steps to Word/Excel](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365668/exporting-test-cases-with-steps-to-wordexcel.html) You could kindly vote up and track the progress.

---

Another way is using  **[Offline Test Execution extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.OfflineTestExecution)**. You can export the entire test plan, or a filtered selection, to an Excel file. Filter the export to the entire test plan, the selected suite with or without children, configuration and/or tester before exporting.

This will view test cases offline in excel as below. But this Add-in can eventually only update the stuff in existing Test Cases. for Ex. You can export scripts to Excel and make them Pass/Fail/Block and again import the Sheet. But if you need to do a fresh Import of Test Cases which you are not able to do.

[image]

But this solution also have a limitation, it will not allow you to be able select with some selective fields.

Hope it helps.